# SQLAlchemy error: invalid transaction. How do I locate the source of the error?

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I'm experiencing an error in my code, but it appears that the genesis for the error is elsewhere.  The error I'm seeing is:

(sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back

Problem is, I have a multi-threaded application accessing the database in a variety of spots.  How can I identify which issue is generating this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had been using a db.session.rollback() to enable an immediate read from a different user session (thinking it would be fine even if no writes were pending).  I was incorrect.  I utilized a db.session.commit() even with no pending writes and it enabled an immediate read from a different user session.